# iterate folders on Google Drive using .net google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I am using C# for google drive api (.net google api). I need to iterate folders on my google drive? how can I do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can list all your Google Drive folders in .NET using the Documents List API, here is a complete snippet showing how to do that in C#:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#retrieving_a_list_of_collections

If your goal is to iterate SkyDrive folders, then the Google Drive SDK won't help you, I guess SkyDrive has an API that you can use.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it out. I mistakenly wrote skydrive instead of google drive.

Comment: Cool, I was a bit confused by your mention of SkyDrive :)